# python runtime 3x deviation for 32 vs 34 char IDs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, aggregation

I am running an aggregation script, which heavily relies on aggregating / grouping on an identifier column. Each identifier in this column is 32 character long as a result of a hashing function.

so my ID column which will be used in pandas groupby has something like

```
e667sad2345...1238a
```

as an entry.

I tried to add a prefix "ID" to some of the samples, for easier separation afterwards. Thus, I had some identifiers with 34 characters and others still with 32 characters.

```
e667sad2345...1238a
IDf7901ase323...1344b
```

Now the aggregation script takes 3 times as long (6000 vs 2000 seconds). And the change in the ID column (`adding the prefix`) is the only thing which happened. Also note, that I generate data separately and save a pickle file which is read in by my aggregation script as input. So the prefix addition is not part of the runtime I am talking about.

So now I am stunned, why this particular change made such a huge impact. Can someone elaborate?

EDIT: I replaced the prefix with suffix so now it is

```
e667sad2345...1238a
f7901ase323...1344bID
```

and now it runs again in 2000 seconds. Does groupby use a binary search or something, so all the ID are overrepresented with the starting character 'I' ?

Comment: what particular change? what do you do in your aggregation script? Did you consider all combinations of the 34 characters? That said, your question is extremely vague, and most likely will get closed.

Comment: Implementation details matter even in the presence of high-level abstractions meant to obscure them -- a deep investigation into CPU cache line usage even running JVM-generated code led to the invention of efficient datastructures for transactional memory, f/e. I wouldn't be the slightest bit surprised if you had something similar going on here. (Then again, maybe it's less obscure, like a length limit beyond which strings are no longer automatically interned)

Comment: (...following up on the above comment, the limit for automatic interning is 20 characters, not 32, so that's not the specific thing you're hitting here).

Comment: From my last edit it is clear, that it is not the length of the identifier, but rather, whether the identifier uses prefix (slow - maybe because one starting character dominates?) vs suffix (fast)

Comment: Ahh! Yeah, this would be a hash-table bucket layout issue.

Comment: more randomness early in the string == fewer collisions. If you've taken a formal computer science program, remember implementing your own hash tables, with a linked list off the end of each one? Not dealing with exactly that, but it's that general class of problem. Honestly, you're lucky it's just a 3x difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had a revelation what is going on.

My entries are sorted using quick sort, which has an expected runtime of O(n * log n). But in worst case, quick sort will actually run in O(n*n). By making my entries imbalanced (20% of data starts with "I", other 80% randomly distributed over alphanumeric characters) I shifted the data to be more of a bad case for quick sort.